# toTitleCase function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert this string into the proper case, but it will not return the correct case. Any idea what is going wrong? (I get no errors).

```
var convert = "this is the end";

String.prototype.toTitleCase = function () {
    var smallWords = /^(a|an|and|as|at|but|by|en|for|if|in|nor|of|on|or|per|the|to|vs?\.?|via)$/i;

    return this.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+[^\s-]*/g, function (match, index, title) {
        if (index > 0 && index + match.length !== title.length &&
  match.search(smallWords) > -1 && title.charAt(index - 2) !== ":" &&
  (title.charAt(index + match.length) !== '-' || title.charAt(index - 1) === '-') &&
  title.charAt(index - 1).search(/[^\s-]/) < 0) {
            return match.toLowerCase();
        }

        if (match.substr(1).search(/[A-Z]|\../) > -1) {
            return match;
        }

        return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1);
    });
};

convert.toTitleCase();

alert(convert);
```

Comment: Did you try to debug step by step?

Comment: FYI "smallWords" are more commonly known an "Stop Words": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words

Comment: Probably because you return a new string. Try `convert = convert.toTitleCase()`

Comment: Why are you writing your own version of this?! Why? http://ejohn.org/files/titleCaps.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `convert.toTitleCase();` is throwing away the result. The method is returning the correct result, but you aren't doing anything with it.

```
var original = "this is the end";

String.prototype.toTitleCase = function () {
    var smallWords = /^(a|an|and|as|at|but|by|en|for|if|in|nor|of|on|or|per|the|to|vs?\.?|via)$/i;

    return this.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+[^\s-]*/g, function (match, index, title) {
        if (index > 0 && index + match.length !== title.length &&
  match.search(smallWords) > -1 && title.charAt(index - 2) !== ":" &&
  (title.charAt(index + match.length) !== '-' || title.charAt(index - 1) === '-') &&
  title.charAt(index - 1).search(/[^\s-]/) < 0) {
            return match.toLowerCase();
        }

        if (match.substr(1).search(/[A-Z]|\../) > -1) {
            return match;
        }

        return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1);
    });
};

var titleCased = original.toTitleCase();

alert(titleCased);
```